# Different fields for add and edit

Tags: python, django

Is there a way of doing this?

Something like:

```
if not obj:
     fields = ( field1, )
else:
     fields = ( field1, field2 )
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and clearest may be a conditional expression:

```
 fields = (field1,field2) if obj else (field1,)
```

Comment: It takes one line of code but involves duplication of `field1`.  If you need to change it in the future then you have to change both occurrences of `filed1`.  So I propose to expand code to three lines: `fields = (field1,)`, `if obj:`, `fields.append(field2)`

Comment: It isn't clear how the OP's data is organized.  If the fields are consecutive elements of a tuple, it gets even simpler:   "fields = t[1 : 2 if obj else 3]".

Comment: yep, for Python core developer it is simpler but not for me %)